# Swift 1.2 Frameworks in XCode 7 / Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Is it possible to build an application in XCode 7 that's written in swift 1.2 or uses frameworks written in swift 1.2?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can't use swift 1.2 anymore with XCode7(/iOS9)

I suggest you to use the Migrator integrated in XCode 7.

You will find it in "Edit -> Convert -> To Latest Swift Syntax"

Comment: Does this mean I have to wait for every single framework I'm using to be ported to swift 2 before I can upgrade to XCode 7?

Comment: If you import a library directly in your project, the migrating tool should do the work (but if it's a really big library it can be quite difficult). If you import a Framework, no action is necessary (it embed compiled code).

Comment: Which library for converting swift 1.2 to 2.0?

Comment: There is no need to use a library, XCode 7 embedded a tool to convert your project from Swift 1.2 to 2.0

Comment: Thank you for quick response. but there are many more syntax error occurs.